# Vine Row Detection in Noisy Image

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, object-detection, image-segmentation

I'm trying to detect vine rows to use in plant health detection and crop yield in an image that contains a lot of trees, other vegetation and insignificant objects. The objects and trees can be in between the vine rows and need to be segmented before further processing. The images are multispectral, taken by UAV.

Plan A is to use DCM and NDVI agricultural indexes, and use a threshold to cut off the ones that are too high for a vine row. However, the UAV we use can give some bad results for DCM so I need a plan B.

Using opencv, I skeletonized the image, which created some connected lines and dots that may be noises. However, removing those dots can lead to information loss, so it's not optimal.

I have seen circle detection methods and Watershed algorithm, but when objects are too close to each other they tend to get grouped together.

The expected result should be that the vine rows and the other images are clearly segmentated from each other. I need someone to guide me in the right direction. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the picture for the field I'm working on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqX5z.jpg

Here's my attempt to segmentate it using DCM and NDVI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEaR3.jpg

Comment: You omitted to include your image, or a Dropbox/GoogleDrive link to it.

Comment: Pictures added.

Comment: I was expecting multi-spectral images...

Comment: Apologies. Here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gZy-k2rAQRBRBT_4bYUsZMNlGU3HY5-e/view?usp=sharing

These images were preprocessed by QGIS and I got each band separately. NDVI is NIR-RED/NIR+RED and DCM is DSM-DTM respectively.

Comment: If you have NIR UAV .tiff image and RED-channel UAV .tiff image that are not captured from the same angle BUT the plant field they depict are the same. How do you match them, so that you take the same pixel (of the same plant field) on both images and calculate the NDVI? IS there any other solution on calculating NDVI??